# How can I make editable fields with button?

Tags: html, css

I've created some fields for nickname, name and .....
Now I would like to make them editable except the nickname.
I've added the buttons, but now I have no idea how to make them editable.....

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-data">
                    <div class="container-data">Personal Information</div>
                    </div>

                                <div class="col-md-8 col-info pull-right">
                                <div class="FirstName">
                                <h7>First Name</h7>
                                <h6><img class="menu-dot" src="img/other/dot.png">John</h6>
                                 <button class="btn btn-success btn-edit pull-right">Edit info</button>
                                </div>
                                 </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-info pull-right">
                                    <div class="LastName">
                                    <h7>Last Name</h7>
                                    <h6><img class="menu-dot" src="img/other/dot.png">Doe</h6>
                                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-edit pull-right">Edit info</button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-info pull-right">
                                        <div class="Email">
                                        <h7>E-mail</h7>
                                        <h6><img class="menu-info" src="img/other/email.png">johndoe@gmail.com</h6>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-edit pull-right">Edit info</button>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8 col-info pull-right">
                                            <div class="DateofBirth">
                                            <h7>Date of Birth</h7>
                                            <h6><img class="menu-info" src="img/other/birth.png">26.2.1901</h6>
                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-edit pull-right">Edit info</button>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-8 col-info pull-right">
                                                <div class="Gender">
                                                <h7>Gender</h7>
                                                <h6><img class="menu-info" src="img/other/gender2.png">Male</h6>
                                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-edit pull-right">Edit info</button>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-info pull-right">
                                                    <div class="Mobile">
                                                    <h7>Mobile Number</h7>
                                                    <h6><img class="menu-info" src="img/other/mobile.png">+21 390 018 78</h6>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-edit pull-right">Edit info</button>
                                                    </div>




    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
h6{
color:#FF6600;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: italic;
}

h7{
color: #000;
font-size: 20px;
}
.container-data{
    color: #A7A7A7;
    position: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

 .col-data{
    width: 75%;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FF6600;
    background: #191919;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 }
 .col-info{
 width: 75%;
 border: 1px solid white;
 padding: 15px 15px;
 background: #E5E5E5;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
       -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;

      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
       -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should use inputs, also h7 should come after h6 - but in your case maybe use a label if you start using input

Comment: How are these values being stored on the server? What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Could you give me an example of edittable field with button?

Comment: What do you want your button to do when click ? What do you mean by editing field ?

Comment: On button click I would like to be able, to change the name for example from John to Fedor

Comment: kittykittybangbang -
MS SQL
MVC C# .NET

Comment: You did NOT create fields, you just printed out some text. Use `<input type="text" />` for editable fields. But you'll need PHP ( in most cases ) to use this data properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help..

```
Name<input type="text" id="name" value="john" readOnly="readonly">

 <button type="button" id="btn" value="yes" class="btn" name="btn">click</button>

$('#btn').click(function(){
     $('#name').attr("readOnly", false);
```

});

Comment: hmmmm.... working fine in the jsfiddle.net but when I launch it from the html file cannot edit the field. 
Maybe I am missing some script src to add?